# How to check multiple compact arguments, passed to a view from multiple controller functions?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Let's say, we have two functions in a controller and these two functions grab data from different tables in the database (i.e. *projects* and *backups*). The return statement of the both functions is a view, activated with different arguments.

```
public function generate_svg_project(){
  //Grabbing the project data
  return view('svg', compact('project'));
}

public function generate_svg_backup(){
  //Grabbing the backup data
  return view('svg', compact('backup');
}
```

Note: There is no case when the both functions will be called at the same time. The idea is to call different set of functions, based on the input data in the view.

Is there a way in the view to check which argument is passed from the controller - *project* or *backup* ?

Comment: I would think that `isset($project)` and `isset($backup)` would work in the view.

Comment: @TimLewis good point. I though about empty() but doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, `empty()` and `isset()` check for different things. You could also do something like `$type = "project";` and `$type = "backup";`, then `compact('type', ...)`, and check `$type` in the view. Few different approaches that could work.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you! I will try your suggestion with the few possible scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just use `@if(isset($value))` in your Blade template